# Is there a container in Java with constant/log insertion time and constant/log access by index time?

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, containers, time-complexity

Is there a container in Java with constant/log insertion time and constant/log access by index time?
Also it needs to be always sorted through comparator.
Like a top 10 score table.

Comment: You can prove, mathematically, that the "needs to be always sorted through comparator" constraint makes this absolutely impossible in any language.  You can satisfy any two of those three constraints, though.

Comment: No, imagine a tree with index to each node. But surely there must be a better way...

Comment: If not sorted require you can use a HashMap for example, but with the sorted condition it makes me impossilbe

Comment: This is not possible, inserting into sorted structure and keeping that structure sorted always take at least log N steps.

Comment: not sorted --> HashMap is constant access/insert.  sorted --> TreeMap is log(n) for access/insert

Comment: @deanosaur You mean "not sorted -> **HashMap**"? TreeMap is always sorted. And even HashMap only has amortized constant access time, and _that's_ assuming a random distribution of hash codes.

Comment: You *can* insert into a tree in constant time, but then you lose efficiency somewhere else (e.g., insertion into a skew binomial heap is constant-time, but remove-min is O(log n)). You can also get O(1) insertion and O(log n) random access into a sorted structure (IIRC), but it's complicated (and fairly recently discovered).

Comment: Note that if your scores are integers, you can use tries or similar, trading dependence on the number of scores for dependence on the sizes of the scores.

Comment: Note that a "top 10 score table" is too small, and too rarely touched, for access speed to even be worth worrying about. Beware premature optimization -- it's a great way to waste developer effort.

Comment: how about top 100000000 then?

Comment: replaced constant to constant OR logarithmic

Comment: Do you really need *random* access, or can you handle *sequential* access? Do you need to be able to remove the smallest element to maintain a bounded size? Think in detail about what you need the data structure to be able to do before trying to choose one.

Comment: One technique is to pick some general data structure that you know will give you all you need (but perhaps inefficiently), write all the code that *uses* that structure, then dig through your code to see what features you really used, consider whether you could avoid some, and then swap in a specialized structure. In general, a simpler, less-capable data structure that's just barely powerful enough for the purpose is likely to be more efficient than a more complex one (even if the more complex one is big-O optimal).

Comment: Also worth noting: for a "top 10" list, even O(N) is constant time, since N is a constant (= 10). That's not just semantics, either; if you go through M values, trying to maintain the top 10 among them (algorithm: insert an element into the container, maintaining sort order; if the container has more than 10 elements, remove the last one), you'll find that the container's insert/get methods don't get any slower whether M=100 or M=100000000. Even if you had a terrible N^2 sort algorithm like bubble sort, there'd still be a constant 121 operations per insert for the sorting.

Answer (score 2):

An [Indexable Skip List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list#Indexable_skiplist) has the properties you desire, although I have not found a standard implementation thereof in Java.  Also check out [Apache Commons Collections TreeList](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/list/TreeList.java#TreeList.AVLNode.get%28int%29).

Comment: Is there a standard Java implementation?

Comment: @user3412974: No. No standard library I know of (and in particular not C++ or Java) has order-statistic augmentation for any of their data structures.

Comment: You can also use just any self-balancing binary search tree.